# Function call parameter, char * vs string default constructor

Tags: c++

While calling a function/method in C++11 and above, which one is better (if any difference)?

Lets assume this function/method:

```
void func(std::string s) { ... }
```

**Which one is best between the following?**

```
func(std::string())
```

or

```
func("")
```

And more generally, **is there any advantage to always call the constructor explicitly during initialization or parameter passing?**

Comment: CLang and g++ do the exact same thing, VC++ is less smart https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PQbHQI

Comment: You have one more option: `func({})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to call the default constructor, because it's guaranteed to not do any unnecessary work.

When passing an empty string literal, it could be that the string implementation does some work processing that string (compute its length for example). An empty string literal isn't a magic bullet that can be treated differently from non-empty string literals. It's type is `const char[1]`, which decays into `const char*`, and that's it - the `std::string` constructor dealing with this literal will end up doing more work than necessary.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for `std::string::string()`:

> Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity). If no allocator is supplied, allocator is obtained from a default-constructed instance.

... and for `std::string::string(const char*)`:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. [...]

For further reading, see also [this short article](https://survex.com/~olly/blog/coding/).

Comment: So it means that `return std::string();` is better than `return "";`, but `return "foo";` and `return std::string("foo");` are equivalent, right?

Comment: Yes. The constructor taking a `const char*` is implicit, that's why both syntaxes work.

Comment: TBH the difference here is probably minuscule - when it is present (gcc and clang optimize both to the same code https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PQbHQI), so, unless you see it's actually a problem by measuring with a profiler I'd go with whatever is clearer (IMO passing `""`).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to compare `func(std::string())` with `func("")`:

1. `func(std::string())`

   - You create an `std::string` object with default parameter is empty string
   - Then pass `std::string` object to `func` function. You pass it by value, and a new `std::string` object will be allocated in stack memory, and call a copy constructor to initialized it.
   - In this case, there are two `std::string` object is allocated.
2. `func("")`

   - You pass an empty string, so compiler will allocate a `std::string` object in stack memory, and use `std::string(const char*)` constructor.
   - In this case, there is only 1 `std::string` object allocated.

So, I think for this specific case, `func("")` maybe better.